# How to undo in ctrl-x mode?

Tags: autocompletion, insert-mode, undo-redo

Let's say I just completed following path using [`Ctrl-x, Ctrl-f`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F)  (twice) and I haven't exited the `Ctrl-x` mode yet and I got

```
/home/john.doe/
```

Let's say I chose `john.doe` accidentally and actually want to go back to `/home` to finally go to

```
/home/jane.doe/
```

Is there a way to undo the last e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> action without losing the whole path (i.e without losing `/home` here)?

To elaborate why I'm asking: If we exit with e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> and then use <kbd>u</kbd>, the whole path will be removed. So in theory one could exit after every completion, but that seems rather cumbersome.

Comment: What about `Ctrl-e`? That will abort the completion, without inserting any of the completion options

Comment: @husB Thanks for the tip! That does work indeed! I just played with it but it seems you can only undo the most recent completion (i.e. `john.doe` in the example above, but it wouldn't work for `home` after that), right?

Comment: Indeed, `Ctrl-e` only _cancels_ the current completion, it does not  _undo_ the completion, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use `i_CTRL-W` and re-enter ^X-mode by `i_CTRL-X i_CTRL-F`. It does of course then exit the ^X-mode + if you do not have `/` as `iskeyword`, which would not be very user friendly, the approach require a few hits from time to time.

If it is something one do frequently enough one could do a remap. For example `i_CTRL-G`:

```vim
:inoremap <C-G>  <ESC>dT/a<BS><C-X><C-F><C-P>
```

It does:

- `<ESC>`: Exit insert mode
- `dT/`: Delete backwards until first `/`
- `a`: enter insert mode
- `<BS>` delete `/`
- `<C-X><C-F>`: Re-open ^X-mode file
- `<C-P>`: Move up one so that the selection is empty. This way we can hit `CTRL-G` multiple times without having to set it to no-selection.

Comment: Note that one is left in normal mode if `dT/` comes up short. Have to look for a fix for that.